# рекурсивный запрос mssql

Tags: sql-server, запрос, рекурсия

Помогите с рекурсивным запросом к таблице, чтобы значение в столбце `flag` родителей был изменен 0 на 1 в случае если у всех его детей стоит 1

```
id  name    ID_PP   parentID    flag
1   Все NULL    NULL    0
2   Компания    NULL    1   0
3   Производство 1  NULL    2   0
4   Производство 2  NULL    2   0
5   Производство 3  NULL    2   0
6   Производство 4  NULL    2   0
7   Производство 5  NULL    2   0
8   Производство 6  NULL    2   0
9   Цех 1   NULL    3   0
10  Цех 2   NULL    4   0
11  Цех 3   NULL    4   0
12  Цех 4   NULL    4   0
13  Цех 5   NULL    5   0
14  Цех 6   NULL    5   0
15  Цех 7   NULL    6   0
16  Цех 8   NULL    6   0
17  Цех  9  NULL    6   0
18  Цех  10 NULL    7   0
19  Цех 11  NULL    7   0
20  Цех 12  NULL    8   1
21  Цех 13  8   1
23  Цех 14  NULL    8   1
24  Отделение 0101  1898    9   1
25  Отделение 0102  2205    9   0
26  Отделение 0103  2064    9   1
27  Отделение 0104  2121    9   0
28  Отделение 0105  2185    9   0
29  УСК             1983            9   0
30  Отделение 0106 (И-7)    5347    9   1

declare @in_bdt datetime = cast('13.02.2018 00:00:00' as datetime)   
declare @in_edt datetime = cast('13.02.2018 23:59:00' as datetime) 
 declare @razn varchar(10) = DATEDIFF (HOUR,@in_bdt,@in_edt)+1

;with rec (  [id]
      ,[ID_PP]
      ,[name]
      ,[parentID]
      ,flag)
  as ( 
  select [id]
      ,t2.[ID_PP]
      ,[name]
      ,[parentID]
      ,flag
   from [dbo].[tab1] 
    left  join(
           SELECT IIF((COUNT([ID_PP])-@razn)=0,1,0) flag
           ,[ID_PP]
                 FROM [dbo].[tab2]
                 where dt between @in_bdt and @in_edt
                 group by  [ID_PP]
           ) as t2 on [tab1].ID_PP = t2.ID_PP

   union all
   select [tab1].[id]
      ,[tab1].[ID_PP]
      ,[tab1].[name]
      ,[tab1].[parentID]  
      ,flag
            from [tab1] 
      join rec on [tab1].id =rec.parentID

   )

select distinct rec.[id]
      ,[ID_PP]
      ,[name]
      ,[parentID]
      ,flag
       from rec
       order by rec.[id]

1   NULL    1
2   1   1
3   2   1
4   2   1
5   2   1
6   2   1
7   2   1
8   2   1
83  2   1
9   3   1
10  4   NULL
11  4   1
12  4   1
13  5   1
14  5   1
15  6   1
16  6   1
17  6   1
18  7   1
19  7   1
20  8   1
21  8   1
23  8   1
24  9   1
25  9   NULL
```

Comment: эта таблица получается JOINом 2 таблиц по столбцу ID_PP с добавлением к 1 столбца flag

Comment: да,все верно, таблица неполна, ниже есть данные со всеми записями, не включил их в код, сейчас изменю,пусть будут дети с парент 8 флаг 1

Comment: SQL Server17, сейчас тоже попробую изучить вышеуказанное решение

Comment: надеюсь на Вашу помощь, но попробую разобраться)

Comment: добавил мой код, но он выводит 2 записи в родителе с флагом 0 и 1, какое условие нужно добавить?

Comment: в запросе flag заменен на raz сейчас поправлю, с его помощью считаю есть ли все записи в отделениях в таблице2

Comment: что за подход??

Comment: да, flag  left JOINится из 2таблицы по  столбцу ID_PP. А куда этот джойн вставить ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
with RTable as(
     select [id],t2.[ID_PP],[name],[parentID], coalesce(flag,0) flag
       from [dbo].[tab1] 
       left  join(
           SELECT IIF((COUNT([ID_PP])-@razn)=0,1,0) flag,[ID_PP]
             FROM [dbo].[tab2]
             where dt between @in_bdt and @in_edt
             group by  [ID_PP]
       ) as t2 on [tab1].ID_PP = t2.ID_PP
),
R1 as(
    select id, ParentId, flag
      from RTable R
     where not exists(select 1 from RTable N where N.parentId=R.Id)
    union all
    select T.id, T.ParentId,
           case when T.flag=1 then 1 else R.flag end
      from R1 R, RTable T
     where T.id=R.ParentId
)
select id, parentId, min(flag) flag
  from R1
group by id, parentId
```

Спускаемся от листьев к корню дерева (лист это такая запись у которой нет наследников). При этом берем флаг из текущей записи, если он 1 или, если он 0, то берем флаг пришедший по рекурсии от наследника. Если по всем возможным путям (от всех листьев) до данного узла дошли только 1, то и итогом данного узла будет 1. На выходе из рекурсии у нас как раз для каждого id есть записи всех его прямых наследников с теми флагами, которые были получены спуском от листьев. Остается только сгруппировать до id и получить минимум (если был хотя бы один 0 - то итог 0)

Пример на [sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/7f773/2)  (только рекурсии, без начальной подготовки таблицы из вашего примера)

Comment: результат неверный выходит,одни нуллы...

Comment: @russotyrusto Я не могу ничего не сказать о результате, когда в вопросе не описано текстом как именно должен получаться флаг и не описана структура двух таблиц а не одной. Я могу только сказать, что рекурсивная часть запроса дает верный результат, в случае если у нее на входе в поле flag строго 0 и 1. сделайте `with RTable (...) select * from RTable` и добейтесь что бы ваш left join дал корректные значения флагов для своих записей (я его просто скопировал от вас, не смотря, что он делает), после этого рекурсия распространит эти флаги вниз по дереву.

Comment: проверил left join он выдает верный результат с flag, проблема в том что флаг 1 распространяется на родителей, хотя у child есть как 0 так и 1 во flag,то есть если есть нулл и 1 он дальше берет 1, это условие нужно добавить дополнительное?

Comment: @russotyrusto Если одна 1 распространится на родителей, это ничего не испортит. потому что в итоге до родителя дойдут все записи и если среди них будет хоть один 0 то итог будет то же 0. Сможете на sqlfiddle создать такую ситуацию как у вас, когда 0 не доходит (правда сейчас он опять тупит :( )

Comment: добавил в вопрос результаты запросы, как видите условие не выполняется...

Comment: @russotyrusto А что там делают NULL ? У вас в изначальном примере данных в поле flag только 0 и 1, в итоге запрос рассчитан именно на это. Ноль - это НЕ NULL !!! сделайте coalesce, что бы они все таки были нулями.

Comment: разобрался,спасибо Вам большое!